Is there a notion of "locally flat" for CW complexes?
A submanifold $X^n\subset Y^m$ is locally flat if each point $x\in X$ has a neighborhood $U\subset Y$ so that $(U,U\cap X)\simeq (\Bbb R^m, \Bbb R^n)$ with the standard embedding $\Bbb R^n\hookrightarrow \Bbb R^m$.
I want something like this for embedded CW complexes. I am mostly interested in 2-dimensional CW complexes embedded into 4-space, but a more general answer is welcome as well.

Question:
Given a CW complex $X$ and a (piecewise-linear) embedding $\phi:X\hookrightarrow Y^m$, can one define a sensible notion of being locally flat for $\phi$? Is there a standard way to do this in the literature?

It is clear how to do this in the interior of top-dimensional cells, but much less clear for points where several cells meet.

Maybe the setting of embedding graphs into surfaces is relevant. Locally at any interior point of an edge the neighborhood looks locally flat. but at each vertex one can have more local structure. This additional structure is given by the cyclid order in which the edges appear (up to reversing the entire order). Interesting examples are the embedding of $S^1\vee S^1$ into a Disc or as the 1-skeleton of $T^2$. I would have trouble calling one of these structures locally flat, or to define locally flat in such a way that it does not uniquely describe the local structure.

Admittedly, I have not thought much about 1-complexes in 2-space. Here links consists of finitely many points on the circle, which leaves not much room for structural diversity. My primary setting embeds 2-complexes in 4-space (a common setting for discussing local flatness with submanifolds). Here a link is a graph in the 3-sphere. The link at an edge of the 2-complex is a 2-vertex graph with several edges between them. This graph can be embedded in 3-space in the obvious way, or very complicated with many knots. Here a distinction into locally flat and not might appear more useful/natural.

I don't see a sensible way to do this for arbitrary CW-complexes, but for regular or semi-simplicial CW-complexes there's probably a few sensible definitions.

Do you have some control over the vertex links in your two-complexes?  (For example, are all vertex links the one-skeleton of a tetrahedron?)  If so, you can insist  that the embedding of vertex links into the three-sphere are "standard".

@RyanBudney I am actually happy with regular complexes. I am not sure what semi-simple means.

@SamNead Unfortunately I don't want to make any such assumptions. The links can be arbitrarily complicated (finite) graphs. Perhaps it sensible to require that every link is embedded as simple as possible.

A start for one definition would be the embedding has a regular neighbourhood that admits a regular CW decomposition such that the projection to $X$ is cellular.  This seems a bit on the weak side, but it's probably what I'd start with until I could find a better definition.

@RyanBudney Interesting approach. Is this equivalent with the usual definition of locally flat on submanifolds (with and without boundary)?

For smooth manifolds its equivalent provided your CW decomposition is "smoothly compatible" with the manifold's smooth structure.  I haven't thought about the topological case in much detail but I would imagine it's equivalent in that case.

Maybe the following example still is interestiing. Take the treefoil knot $S^1\hookrightarrow S^3$ and suspend it to get a nonstandard embedding.  Then the neighborhoods at the two poles look weird, e.g. they are not locally flat near these points. Can't you still find a nice CW structure on a neighborhood such that the projection is cellular ?

@HenrikRüping Do you say this might be a counterexample to Ryan's suggestion?

It might be. I haven't constructed any regular CW-structure on a neighborhood with the projection.
